# Validar campos dentro de divs separadas num único form

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Dentro de um único `form` eu tenho 3 `divs`, que vão mudando conforme o usuário clica em `próximo`. Mas pro usuário poder clicar em `próximo` os campos obrigatórios da `div` que está sendo mostrada atualmente devem estar preenchidos.

Pra fazer a validação do `form` tem um código da seguinte forma:

```
var form_validation = function() {
    var e = function() {
            jQuery(".form-valide").validate({
                ignore: [],
                errorClass: "invalid-feedback animated fadeInDown",
                errorElement: "div",
                errorPlacement: function(e, a) {
                    jQuery(a).parents(".form-group > div").append(e)
                },
                highlight: function(e) {
                    jQuery(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("is-invalid").addClass("is-invalid")
                },
                success: function(e) {
                    jQuery(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("is-invalid"), jQuery(e).remove()
                },
                rules: {
                  "nome_campo":{
                       required: !0
                   }
                },
                messages:{
                    "nome_campo":{
                         required: "mensagem a ser mostrada quando não preenchido"
                     }
                }
            })
    }
    return {
        init: function() {
            e(), a(), jQuery(".js-select2").on("change", function() {
                jQuery(this).valid()
            })
        }
    }
}();
jQuery(function() {
    form_validation.init()
});
```

Dessa forma eu consigo especificar o campo que é obrigatório e a mensagem de erro a ser mostrada. Mas até onde pesquisei eu só consigo fazer isso pra tag `form`, mas não pra `div`.

Eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de fazer algo parecido para as `divs` e só permitir passar pra próxima `div` quando todos os campos obrigatórios estiverem preenchidos e assim por diante até chegar na `div` que permite clicar em `salvar`. Mas se o usuário clicar em `próximo` e os campos obrigatórios não estiverem preenchidos que mostre as mensagens de erro.

Comment: Poderia tentar ajudar se conseguisse reproduzir o código, e para isso precisaria do HTML do formulário.

Comment: Vo tentar colocar aqui, o complicado que é código da empresa que faço estágio, ai não da pra mostrar muito. Vou mudar umas coisas nele e ja posto. Vlwzaço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente, é possível que você valide os campos antes de mostrar a próxima `div`

A baixo eu fiz um exemplo, para você poder ter uma ideia, você pode executar para ver o comportamento.

```js
function goToDiv2(){
  const nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  const validator = nome.length > 0;
  nextDiv('div-1','div-2',validator,'error-message-1')
}

function goToDiv3(){
  const idade = document.getElementById('idade').value;
  const validator = idade >= 18;
  nextDiv('div-2','div-3',validator,'error-message-2')
}

function submitData(){
  const fone = document.getElementById('telefone').value;
  const validator = fone.trim().length > 10
  nextDiv('div-3',null,validator,'error-message-3')
  if(validator){
    alert('tudo certo')
  }
}

function nextDiv(currentDivId, nextDivId, validator, elementErroId){
  const div = document.getElementById(currentDivId)
  const nextDiv = document.getElementById(nextDivId)
  if(!validator){
    const small = document.getElementById(elementErroId)
    small.innerHTML = div.dataset.erro_msg
    return;
  }
  div.classList.toggle('hide')
  if(nextDiv){
    nextDiv.classList.toggle('hide')  
  }
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}

small{
  color : red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1" data-erro_msg="o nome não pode ser vazio"> 
  <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
  <input id="nome" placeholder="insira seu nome"/> 
  <button onclick="goToDiv2()"> next </button>
  <small id="error-message-1"> </small> 
</div>
<div class="hide" id="div-2" data-erro_msg="você precisa ser maior de idade"> 
  <label for="idade">Idade: </label>
  <input type="number" id="idade" placeholder="insira sua idade"/> 
  <button onclick="goToDiv3()"> next </button>
  <small id="error-message-2"> </small> 
</div>
<div class="hide" id="div-3" data-erro_msg="insira o telefone com o DDD"> 
  <label for="telefone">Telefone: </label>
  <input id="telefone" placeholder="insira seu telefone"/> 
  <button onclick="submitData()"> next </button>
  <small id="error-message-3"> </small> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A resposta foi a base perfeita pro que eu precisava.

Só fiz algumas adaptações e vou deixar aqui pra caso alguém também precise.

```
//Essa aqui é chamada no .ready pra esconder as labels dos erros antes de mostrar

function hideErrorDiv1() { //Idem pra div2
    const elementErroId = ["erro-id1", "erro-id2", "erro-id3"];

    hideElements(elementErroId);
}

function hideElements( elementErroId ) {

        for (let index = 0; index < elementErroId.length; index++) {
            const field = elementErroId[index];
            const element = document.getElementById(field);
            $(element).hide();   
        }
}

goToDiv2() {
    const elementId = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

    const elementErroId = ["erro-id1", "erro-id2", "erro-id3"];

    goToNextDiv("div1", "div2", elementErroId, elementId);
}

goToDiv3() {
    const elementId = ["id4", "id5", "id6"];

    const elementErroId = ["erro-id4", "erro-id5", "erro-id6"];

    goToNextDiv("div2", "div3", elementErroId, elementId);
}

function goToNextDiv( currentDivId, nextDivId, elementErroId, elementId ) {
    const div = document.getElementById(currentDivId);
    const nextDiv = document.getElementById(nextDivId);
    var canGoNext = true;

    for (let index = 0; index < elementId.length; index++) {
        const field = document.getElementById(elementId[index]);
        const errorLabel = document.getElementById(elementErroId[index]);

        if($(field).val() == null || $(field).val() == 0) {
            canGoNext = canGoNext && false;
            $(errorLabel).show();
        } 
        else {
            canGoNext = canGoNext && true;
            $(errorLabel).hide();
        }

    }

    if(canGoNext) {

        $(div).hide();
        $(nextDiv).show();
    }
}
```

**Html:**

```
<form>
    <div id="div1">

        <div>
            <label>Nome Campo</label>
            <input type="text" id="id1">
            <label id="erro-id1">Preenchimento Obrigatório</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Nome Campo</label>
            <input type="text" id="id2">
            <label id="erro-id2">Preenchimento Obrigatório</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Nome Campo</label>
            <input type="text" id="id3">
            <label id="erro-id3">Preenchimento Obrigatório</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="goToDiv2()"> Próximo </button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="div2">
        <!--similar div1-->
    </div>

</form>
```